# Meteor - Signed Release Version APK does NOT work. Run android-device works

Tags: android, cordova, ssl, meteor

I am having trouble with the signed apk. When I run the Android app from meteor it works.

i.e this works: `meteor run android-device --mobile-server=https://x.y`

But the following case doesn't work: as soon as I create a signed apk from either mup or from meteor build, the signed apk stops working, whereas the unsigned apk worked before. The app opens on the phone, shows the index.html but when I click sign in on the accounts-ui nothing happens.

The signed apk uploads to the play store, but the downloaded apk shows `index.html` content and then nothing. I click the sign in button, nothing happens.

I have seen several people raising this issue and have tried all of them, still, it doesn't work.

Things I tried:

- change --server, mobile-server flags in several ways
- check ssl certificate intermediaries
- change CN in certificate
- change root_url, DDP url, mobile_root_url, mobile ddp url

Nothing works.

Here is the logcat:

> 02-08 13:13:27.683 3698 9958 E BoostFramework: Exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object,
>   java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference

Please help. Now my app is ready for publishing, I have been cracking my head over this for a few days.